# Cannot access samba Ubuntu server via hostname UNC path (IP works) in Windows explorer

Tags: samba, server-message-block, windows-explorer

#### Setup

We have an AD server running on Windows Server 2012 (`ad01.<domainroot>`). There is a Samba file server running on Ubuntu 20.04 (`fs02.<domainroot>`). The file server is domain joined using winbind.

In this post I'll be using *<domainroot>* to be the equivalent placeholder of *AD.EXAMPLE.ORG* and *<workgroup>* for the workgroup.

#### Problem

We're unable to access the samba server / shares via its hostname, we get a network error claiming it's unreachable:

[image] .

The issue is the same if using the FQDN.

If I navigate to it via it's IP (`\\<fs02 IP>`), it works without issue, so the shares themselves seem to be correct. (smb.conf added below)

#### What I've tried

My initial thought was to check DNS, but `nslookup fs02` gives me the correct response. I can also ping it without issue.

I've also tried to fiddle with the `smb.conf`, this is the configuration I'm currently using:

```
[global]
security = domain

workgroup=<workgroup>
realm=<domainroot>
netbios name = fs02

# === logging config ===
log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
log level = 1

# === Backend setup ===

idmap config * : backend = tdb
idmap config * : range = 2000-9999
idmap config <workgroup> : backend = rid
idmap config <workgroup> : range = 10000-30000

winbind use default domain = yes
winbind nested groups = yes
winbind refresh tickets = yes

inherit owner = yes
vfs objects = acl_xattr
map acl inherit = yes
store dos attributes = yes

unix extensions = yes

# === Share definitions ===
# ... pruned ...
```

Comment: The SMB client might add the DNS-suffix. Does nslookup work with the DNS-suffix. Do client and server have the same DNS-suffix?

Comment: nslookup works with both `fs02` or `fs02.<domainroot>`, I'm planning on setting up a separate test server next week to see if I can recreate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue in my case was due to a faulty NTP configuration causing time drift between various servers. Resetting the clock manually verified the issue, and fixing the NTP configuration prevented drift from being an issue again.